# Which is faster...sequential script or instantiated class?

Tags: php, performance, runtime

Just a quick question about runtime...is it faster to run a script with many sequential commands or instantiate a new class object that calls each method to equal the same number of calls. Essentially what I'm asking is if writing "new Example();" and having it run through all of the methods is faster or slower than running through all the code in one sequential script. In my mind, I am imagining this in PHP.

```
<?php
echo new Example();
class Example
{
    function __toString(){
        $this -> method1();
        $this -> method2();
        $this -> method3();
        $this -> method4();
    }

    function method1(){
        //contents1;
    }

    function method2(){
        //contents2;
    }

    function method3(){
        //contents3;
    }

    function method4(){
        //contents4;
    }
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php
//contents1;
//contents2;
//contents3;
//contents4;
?>
```

Which one is faster or is it trivial and/or compiler dependent?

Answer (score 0):

There will be added overhead when constructing a new object and calling the methods. But not much.

Other than that I don't think there would be much impact on speed, space however might very slightly because of the where PHP put things.

Objects are useful in OO design, scripts that are just meant to run once may as well be stand alone.

There are a bunch of other things like stack traces with objects as pet non-objects as well that might change if an error is encountered.

But to answer your question - minimal speed impact aside from the overhead of building / interpreting the object for php.

Further to this, read up on "time complexity" and "big oh" notation. The difference between sequential steps is trivial compared to how speed changes depending on your input 'n' and the complexity of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

OOP will not affect the performance of your web application however there are several things that will, such as large amounts of data on the page, calling external web services and not setting time limits (RSS Feeds), large image files or lots of image files on a page, and hitting the database over and over again on post backs when it is not necessary. There are several other things which will hit the performance of your site but these are the basics.